# Rails 3.1 rake assets:precompile failing

Tags: rake, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Anyone seen this before?  If not, any good tips on debugging rake issues w/ no stack trace would be appreciated!

My site's running fine in dev, since assets are not compiled, but the compilation of my assets is failing, and I'm not getting a useful stacktrace, even w/ the --trace flag

All I'm seeing is:

> rake assets:precompile --trace                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1 ↵
>   ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
>   ** Execute assets:precompile
>   rake aborted!
>   undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

Any suggestions? Thanks
-jeff

Comment: THANK YOU!  That didn't fix it, but it did give me the stack traces that showed that I have other values that are unavailable (environment variables do not exist, because precompile does not depend on :environment)  So now I know where to look.  Thanks Daniel!